# Extra style attribute added by Apex in IFrame

Tags: iframe, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to open Oracle Apex application inside an iframe. I have an index.jsp which has the following code

```html
<body>
     <iframe id="apexiFrame" 
            width="100% !important" height="100% !important" 
            src="http://localhost:9999/ords/f?p=101">
     </iframe>
</body>
```

If I change localhost to system name, login page loads fine but when I go to the next page after login and in all other subsequent pages, I can see an extra style attribute is getting added and hence apex application occupies only half of the iframe

[image]

I am not able to find from where this style attribute is getting added. Please help.

**Update:**

I added jquery to remove the extra style attribute on page load.

```js
$('iframe').load( function() {

    $("iframe").removeAttr("style");

});
```

Though it does the trick still there is a delay of 1 second between the iframe loading (with style tag) and then removing it because of which the iframe width changing from 500px to 100% is noticeable. If there is a way to avoid the style tag getting added automatically, that will be the ideal solution I guess. Any leads please?

Comment: What version of Oracle Apex?  Upgrade to at least 5.1 (most current is I think 18.1 with their new calendar version numbering).  Also add a oracle-apex-x.x version tag.  There have been a lot of improvements in how APEX does their styling, but within an `iframe` you may be stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your time Mark. Apex version used is 5.1.4.00.08.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added jquery to remove the extra style attribute on iframe load and restarted the server.

> $('iframe').load( function() {
>
> > $("iframe").removeAttr("style");
>
> });

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up CSS inside your `IFRAME` HTML tag. The `width=` and `height=` should be either pixels `width=500` or percentage `height=100%`.  That may be causing the issue.

You could try

```html
 <iframe id="apexiFrame" 
        style="height:100%;width:100%;" 
        src="http://localhost:9999/ords/f?p=101">
 </iframe>
```

Not sure where the !important would go on the style tag.

Now, to see if you can get rid of APEX's style, open up your application in APEX Designer, App Builder tab, choose "Shared Components" and in the User Interface block, wander around the Themes and Templates links.

[image: App Builder User Interface links]

Comment: I tried adding style="height:100%;width:100%;"  like you suggested  and on iframe load, I could see that it is getting replaced by the height and width I mentioned in the question. I checked the templates link and could not find from where this style is getting added. After server restart the delay of 1 sec before the iframe load and jquery to remove style execution is gone and I decided to go with that solution. Thank you for your time and help is appreciated.